# Should my Static Images be in /pub or root? Magento 2

Tags: magento2

My product pages have landing pages with images. So when you scroll down in the description I have hard coded landing pages with images.

Those images are manually uploaded in my public_html/landingpage

So it is in the root of Magento.

Now my question is, if I should move it to /pub/landingpage

Answer (score 2):

Best place is root/pub/media folder. It's specially designed for user uploaded media files

Comment: Btw, does that foldder ever get deleted by magento? when you clean cache or storage? Because those images are not uploaded by magento, but by me in cpanel. Those are images like for about page ect...

Comment: no, Magento never clean up pub/media folder by self

Answer (score 0):

Please check below url, I think its very helpful to you.

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Images-not-loading-on-product-View-page/m-p/65593#M2246